# How to run jquery inside angularjs modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using [ngDialod](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) for my modal window in angularjs.

i want to run some jquery code inside the modal window.

I have created a fiddle [My Modal](http://jsfiddle.net/hareeshmh/mb6o4yd1/). How to target `id="target"` on click?

*(Why i need this because, i am planning a simple image slider inside modal)*

Please help,

Comment: It would be appreciated if you post your code here and not only on JSfiddle.

Comment: Sorry i don't have any code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer

http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/6/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">

        <div id="target" ng-click="test()" ng-controller="tt">
          Click here
        </div>
    </script>

</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {

    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' });
    };

}
function tt($scope)
{
    $scope.test = function()
    {
        console.log("AaA");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass controller to ngDialog and use ng-click

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {

    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId',
                       controller : 'dialogCtr'});
    };


}

myApp.controller('dialogCtr', function($scope){
    $scope.clickTarget = function()
    {
        alert("hello");
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
        <div ng-click="clickTarget()" id="target">
          Click here
        </div>
    </script>

</div>
```